# Route and transform data from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-flink, azure-stream-analytics

in our usecase, we receive messages on Azure IoT Hub, and would like to route the data to different Event Hubs or Service Bus topics.

IoT Hub routes and endpoints are no option, because the data is binary data (protobuf), and there are only 10 different endpoints possible (we need more).

Our requierements are:

- Splitting the message
- Transform the data (maybe json)
- Routing to different endpoints based on the payload (different parts of message could be routed to different endpoints)
- (optional) enrich the data with additional payload

I see different options:

- Azure Stream Analytics
- Azure Functions
- Spark or Flink
- Do it yourself (write an Application and run it in Service Fabric or Kubernets)

Which techology would you recommend?

Regards,
Markus

Comment: Hi. At this time Azure Stream Analytics only supports JSON, CSV and AVRO, so it won't be able to read the incoming message if it's binary. If you can transform it before (e.g. with Azure function), you can process it further in Stream Analytics.

Comment: what is the data size?

Comment: @romanKiss the data size depends, because of very different messages. But in generell I would say, it's small. Maximum a few Kb, the most below 1 Kb.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option for your scenario such as using an *Azure Event Grid.*  In this case, the telemetry data from the Azure IoT Hub are pushed to the Event Grid via its custom topic endpoint. Note, that there is a limit for the event message such as 64KB, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema).

The Event Grid allows to subscribe unlimited number of the Event Hubs, more details about the Event Grid are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-event-grid-now-supports-event-hubs-as-a-destination/).

Based on the above, the following screen snippet shows your another option for routing a small telemetry data to more than 10 Event Hubs, basically to any kind of subscriber.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this sharing this option! 
So the parsing, splitting and transforming of the messages would happen in the function, right? So, why to push the events from the function to the Event Grid instead of pushing them direct to the different Event Hubs?

Comment: Yes, the AF has a responsibility for decomposition of the binary telemetry data into the array of the small events in the json formatted text. This is a straightforward stateless processing task with a properly error handling within the body of the AF and very well scalable. In the above solution, each event from the received array is routed and delivered based on the subscriptions to the subscribers in the Event Grid. Pushing these events to the many different Event Hubs direct from the AF can be done only using an imperative bindings with a poor scalability, error handling and manageability.